# Notification system in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to implement notification system in my webapp. Small bell icon, where after click, there will be listed all notifications to a specified user. I tried with websocket, but simplebroker does not hold messeges in queue and cilent must be connected, when server sends message, to recieve it. How can I achieve that notification system?

Thanks.

Comment: Webflux can do the trick. https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best, quick, and robust solution to this problem is to use Fire Cloud Messaging. Its completely free and allows you to send reactive notification messages to your client app from your spring app.

There are many examples online showing you how to integrate this into your spring app.
Check this out for example: [FCM integration with Spring](https://medium.com/@singh.pankajmca/fcm-integration-with-spring-boot-to-send-push-notification-from-server-side-1091cfd2cacf)